# Infopath : convert number to words .

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

I want to convert Info Path number Field to Word

Ex. I have no. `1000` -> `Ten Thousand` like that please help me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there's no built-in way to achieve this - you'll have to write custom code.
This link might help you converting numbers to text.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/53072